# How to make viewport-relative font-size respond to browser zoom in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, viewport, font-size

I am trying to create a fixed position navigation element the height of which takes up to a certain percentage of the viewport height. This is achievable using Viewport Units:

```css
.header-nav {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    height: min(10vh, 50px);
    ...
}
```

Note that the same effect will be observed if either the window is resized or the browser zoom level is adjusted.

Within this navigation element, I would like to achieve the same effect for the size of text so that it does not overflow, and so my `font-size` needs to respond to my viewport size as well

```css
.header-nav {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    height: min(10vh, 50px);
    font-size: min(1.5vh, 16px);
    ...
}
```

Here is the problem: on Safari, Viewport Units as applied to `font-size` will respond to changes in the viewport induced by resizing the window, but *not* by changing the browser zoom level. Thus, if the window size does not change, `1.5vh` resolves to a fixed pixel value, which is susceptible to UI scaling, and results in text overflow as the browser zoom level is increased.

I have tried using the [CSS "locks"](https://css-tricks.com/css-locks/) technique to achieve the desired effect, however this solution relies on using Viewport Units to calculate the current size of the viewport, and so suffers from the same issue.

I can use media queries to provide roughly the same effect:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header-nav {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .header-nav {
        font-size: 8.33px;
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .header-nav {
        font-size: 7.14px;
    }
}

/* ...and so on */
```

This would solve the overflow issue, but it's not perfect, and would cause the text to snap to (slightly) different sizes as the browser zoom level is increased (not to mention it's a lot more code).

Is what I am trying to do possible in Safari using only CSS?

Answer (score 0):

`vh` and `vw` units are always "locked" to the size of viewport regardless the zoom level it remains the same.

If you want to change your font-size according to the zoom level use `rem` property instead which is bound to the root element font size which changes with the zoom level.

```
font-size: min(1rem, 16px);
```